# A problem of increasing sequence of compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

The following is the problem from a past homework set.

> Suppose a set $ A \subset  \Bbb R^{n} $ is a union of increasing compact sets $A=\cup_{i=0}^\infty  A_{i}$. Suppose there is also a compact set $C$ such that
>   for each $i \in \Bbb N  $ for each $ x \in A$\ $A_{i}$  dist($x$,C)$ <\frac 1i $
>   Prove that the closure of the set A satisfies $\bar A \subset A \cup C $.

I let $x \in \bar A$ and there fore there exist a sequence $<x_n>$ in $A$ which converges to $x$.

Then to use the distance property, I supposed I could find a subsequence $<y_n>$ such that $y_i$ does not belong to $A_i$.

(If such a subsequence could not be find there is a set $A_n$ which contains all but a finite number of elements is  and therefore since $A_n$ is closed $x \in A_n $, and $x \in A$)
Now I think I can use the distance property to show $x$ is a limit point of $C$.

But I haven't used the compactness of either $C$ or $A_i$ so I think I have done something wrong.

Please give me some hint on how to approach this problem.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you used the compactness of both $C$ _and_ $A_i$ (rather, you used the fact that they are closed; I wonder whether we get any nasty counterexamples from letting the $A_i$ be unbounded).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SKETCH: Suppose that $x\in(\operatorname{cl}A)\setminus A$, and let $\sigma=\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ be a sequence in $A$ converging to $x$. For each $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ we have $x\notin A_k$, so $\Bbb R^n\setminus A_k$ is an open nbhd of $x$, and there is an $m_k\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $x_\ell\notin A_k$ whenever $\ell\ge m_k$. Thus, by passing to a subsequence of $\sigma$ if necessary, we may as well assume that $x_k\notin A_k$ for each $k\in\Bbb Z^+$. But then $\operatorname{dist}(x_k,C)<\frac1k$ for each $k\in\Bbb Z^+$, so there is a $y_k\in C$ such that $\|x_k-y_k\|<\frac1k$. $C$ is compact, so $\langle y_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ has a convergent subsequence, converging to some $y\in C$, and it’s not hard to check that $y=x$.

I used the compactness of $C$ to get a convergent subsequence of $\langle y_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$; I did not use compactness of the sets $A_k$, but I did use the fact that they are closed.

Comment: great answer!!!